# How do I create a graph from two groups of data without selecting data row by row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

Say you have this data:

```
First group of data:

        A B C D E
      a 0 1 3 4 5
      b 6 7 8 9 5 
      c 0 1 2 3 4

Second group of data:

        A B C D E
      a 1 1 5 4 5
      b 6 8 8 5 5 
      c 0 3 2 2 1
```

Same number of rows and colums, different data.

Now you want to create a line chart with 3 data series, named a, b and c, like the rows in the data groups, and you need the series to have the X values from the first group and the Y values from the second group. That is:

- "a" series: X values are the "a" row from the first group (0,1,3,4,5) and Y values are the "a" row from the second group (1,1,5,4,5).
- "b" series: "b" row from the first group as X values and "b" row from the second group as Y values, etc.
- "c" series: ...

**How can I do this without having to "select data" row by row from each group?**

This is a simplification of my problem, the truth is those data groups are pretty far appart, and it is a nightmare to select the X values from the first group and then scroll very far away to the second group and select the Y values from it. *(without not forgetting to press CTRL, so I don't unselect the X values from a skyscraper above)*

Comment: You will want VBA.

Comment: Do I repost on another place?

Comment: Your best bet would be to start coding, then come back here or on https://stackoverflow.com/ if you hit a roadblock

Comment: If I faced this spreadsheet dilemma, I'd set up another range, either on this sheet or on a second sheet, which link to the far away data. this new helper range has everything close together, so it's easier to select what you need.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing, yes. Thank you tho.